# How can I hide the search bar in my Vue.js application when a link is clicked in a child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the innermost child component which is home-book-line:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="items && items.length > 0">
      <nuxt-link :to="`/books/${item.id}`" @click="closeAndHideSearchBar" class="d-flex align-center pb-4 pr-2" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <v-img width="30" height="44" contain :src="item.image" class="bookImage" />
        <div class="mr-3 text-right">
          <span class="body4-medium" style="color: #262626">{{ item.title }} / </span>
          <span class="body4-medium" style="color: #262626" v-for="(associate, index) in item.associates.author" :key="associate.id">
            {{ associate.title }}
            {{ index < item.associates.author.length - 1 ? ', ' : '' }}
          </span>
          <span class="caption3-regular s60--text d-block" v-for="associate in item.associates.category" :key="associate.id">{{ associate.title }}</span>
        </div>
      </nuxt-link>
    </div>
    <div v-else class="body1-medium text-center mt-4">نتیجه ای یافت نشد.</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "bookLink",
  props: ['items'],
  methods: {
    closeAndHideSearchBar() {
      this.$emit('closeSearchBar');
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

and this component use in the other child component which is home-search-bar-app component:

```
<template>
  <v-card class="borderRadius-4 pa-2" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(145, 145, 145, 0.15) !important" :showSearchBar.sync="showSearchBar">
    <v-row class="ma-0">
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-tabs v-model="tabs" color="#091E42">
          <v-tab href="#all">همه</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#book">نام کتاب</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#category">موضوع</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#editor">نام نویسنده</v-tab>
        </v-tabs>
        <x-hr />
      </v-col>

      <v-col cols="8">
        <div>
          <v-tabs-items v-model="tabs">
            <v-tab-item value="all">
              <home-book-link v-if="allBookLoadig" :items="allSearchResult" @closeSearchBar="closeSearchBar" />
              <!-- <home-expansion-panels :panels="panels" /> -->
            </v-tab-item>

            <v-tab-item value="book">
              <home-book-link v-if="bookNameLoading" :items="bookNameSearchResult" @closeSearchBar="closeSearchBar" />
              <!-- <home-expansion-panels :panels="panels" /> -->
            </v-tab-item>
            
            <v-tab-item value="category">
              <home-book-link v-if="categoryLoading" :items="categorySearchResult" @closeSearchBar="closeSearchBar" />
            </v-tab-item>
            <v-tab-item value="editor">
              <home-book-link v-if="authorLoading" :items="authorSearchResult" @closeSearchBar="closeSearchBar" />
            </v-tab-item>
          </v-tabs-items>
        </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SearchBarApp",
  props: { toggle: false, searchText: String, showSearchBar: false },
  methods: {
    closeSearchBar() {
      this.$emit('close');
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

and this component use in parent like this:

```
            <v-col cols="7" style="position: relative" class="px-0 mx-2">
              <x-input
                class="body3-regular serach-input"
                id="grey"
                placeholder="جستجو نام کتاب، موضوع یا نام نویسنده"
                appendIcon="mdi-magnify"
                v-model="searchText"
                @input="showSearchBar = searchText.length > 0"
              />

              <home-search-bar-app
                ref="searchBar"
                :showSearchBar.sync="showSearchBar"
                @close="showSearchBar = false"
                style="position: absolute;top: 90px;left: 0px"
                :search-text="searchText"
                @changeSearch="(val) => changeSearch(val)"
                class="d-none d-sm-block w-full"
              />
            </v-col>
```

I want I can be able to hide the home-search-bar-app when i click the home-book-link component and showSearchBar must be false and i want handle emit event but i try so hard and dont get any result.if anyone could help me i will very happy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you using `v-if` or `v-show` on the element you want to hide/show. I think `v-if="showSearchBar"` should do it. So when "showSearchBar" is false the element will be removed, when it's true it will be added in.

`v-if` will remove the element from the DOM and `v-show` will only hide it.
I hope this helps.

Comment: I even use v-if but it does not work. I want when typing in x-input component to show me the home-search-bar-app component(it does work). and if I click an item of the tab in the home-book-link component this home-search-bar-app should disappear but this does not work